# RxJS map & other operators with Observable

Tags: angular, rxjs, angularfire2

Having some real issues with how to achieve the following. I have a service with a function that returns a list of events with a key. I then want to pass this key to another function, which returns a more detailed object, in other data such as number of messages and owner information. Then I subscribe in component.

Currently I am using a .map operator with a forEach and then a subscribe to get the other info. I think I need to use a switchMap (to remove the inner subscribe) but cannot for the life of me get this to work. Have also tried flatMat, MergeMap, forkJoin and Observable.from but just confusing myself. Relevant start of code is below

```
return this.afs.collection<Event>(`users/${this.currentFirebaseUserObj.uid}/eventsByUser`)
    .valueChanges()
    .map((allEvents) => {allEvents.forEach(event =>{
```

Now I want to return the result of the `getCompleteEvent()` function, which returns an Observable of type Event to replace the above event object, and I am thinking I need to subscribe to this, but how can I return the result of the second call and replace the first Event Object i.e.

```
this.getCompleteEvent(event.key).subscribe(completeEvent => {
        return completeEvent
    }
```

On the other hand I can add specific fields to the Event Object in the forEach via different functions, but wanted a `getComplete` function to return the entire object after subscribing i.e.

```
event.userOwnerObj = this.getUserObject(event.ownerId);
event.noOfMessage = this.getNoOfMessages(event.key);
```

Feels like a mess and not sure of the best way to structure this part.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I have everything clear, but this may help.

Let's assume that

```
this.afs.collection<Event>(`users/${this.currentFirebaseUserObj.uid}/eventsByUser`).valueChanges()
```

returns an Observable which emits a collection with all the events, at least in their initial configuration, i.e. with the key but not all of the details.

If this is the case, then consider this code

```
this.afs.collection<Event>(`users/${this.currentFirebaseUserObj.uid}/eventsByUser`).valueChanges()
.switchMap(allEvents => from(allEvents))
```

This returns a stream which emits for *each event* found in `allEvents`. Now, for every *event*, you can run `this.getCompleteEvent(event.key)` which returns an Observable of the *complete event*.

Now you an use the `mergeMap` operator (formerly known as `flatMap`) to **flatten**  the stream of Observables and obtain a stream of *complete events*. This means

```
this.afs.collection<Event>(`users/${this.currentFirebaseUserObj.uid}/eventsByUser`).valueChanges()
.switchMap(allEvents => from(allEvents))
.mergeMap(event => this.getCompleteEvent(event.key))
.subscribe(completeEvent => console.log(completeEvent) // do stuff with completeEvent)
```

Comment: Many thanks for the quick reply. I have tried this, but it errors on the 'from' on the switchMap line. I cant find out where this comes from, apart from Array.from? Sorry I have tried Array.from and the compilation error goes away, just trying to work through your code now. Will report back (y)

Comment: this indeed does get me nearer. The difference now is that if I subscribe in the component, I do get a stream of (complete) Event objects, instead of a list that I subscribed to before (this.completeEvents = events) style. I tried to push these onto a new array in the component, but the issue (when I try with push) is that if another user changes an event, this creates multiple new opjects. TLDR: is there anyway in the above code to return a array of Event objects to subscribe to in the component?

Comment: `from` is a function in RxJs 6. If you are on RxJs 5.x, then you can import it using `import { from } from 'rxjs/observable/from'`

Comment: try `toArray` operator

Comment: thanks, added the from import that works. Added .toArray() underneath  the .switchMap but it errors (this.afs.collection...toArray is not a function). currently looking through  past questions on SO but if you have any guidance on how to fix that would be great

Comment: It should be after mergeMap just before subscribe

Comment: sorry meant to say that I did have it underneath mergeMap() i.e. the last thing (I have removed the subscribe to do in component)